# How can I have HTML5 FileApi Support in Flex?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, html

I need Flex code to support HTML5 File API. Because I need to support File API feature for those browsers that did not support File API. Do you have any code or link?

Comment: I suppose the File API is JavaScript, so you'll have to use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Comment: Using the ExternalInterface class, you can call an ActionScript function in the Flash runtime, using JavaScript in the HTML page. The ActionScript function can return a value, and JavaScript receives it immediately as the return value of the call. This is for using AS command from JavaScript. But I need the reverse for those browsers that did not support File API. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I a few things to say.  First most of the [Flash File API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) is AIR only, so will not work in a browser based application.  [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) will work in a browser app, but depends on what you're trying to do explicitly.

To communicate between JavaScript and ActionScript; you can use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

You can use ExternalInterface to call JavaScript functions from ActionScript.  [Info on that.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.5/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f31.html)

You can also use ExternalInterface to call ActionSCript functions from JavaScript.  [Here is some info on that](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.5/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e92.html).