# Google Speech API + Flex API

Tags: apache-flex, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

This might be considered a very broad question but, I am trying to introduce speech into a web application built using Flex API.
My initial plan is to introduce something like the Google homepage with a text box and a mic icon which will trigger the speech api on click.

Having done research, I havent found a way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google speech API is implemented in browser on client side in javascript, the detailed documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/01/Voice-Driven-Web-Apps-Introduction-to-the-Web-Speech-API?hl=en).

To communicate between javascript and flex you can use [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f17.html)

Similar question is [How can I have HTML5 FileApi Support in Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139991/how-can-i-have-html5-fileapi-support-in-flex)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. However, since the web-app primarily runs on chrome, I cannot use ExternalInterface. EI does not provide chrome support. I will look into alternatives and post what I find here.

Comment: I've used ExternalInterface without problems in Chrome browser.